# How to use rails secure_compare?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I have tried

```
line:60  mv = ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier.new
         return nil unless mv.secure_compare(a, b)
```

which gives the error

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2):
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:29:in `initialize'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:60:in `new'
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier/secure_compare

## Edit

The active support method was private so I just copied the method directly into application controller.

```
   def secure_compare(a, b)
    return false unless a.bytesize == b.bytesize

    l = a.unpack "C#{a.bytesize}"

    res = 0
    b.each_byte { |byte| res |= byte ^ l.shift }
    res == 0
  end
```

Is there any blatant security concern with doing this or using this implementation?

Answer (score 8):

`secure_compare` is a public class method of ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils since rails 4.2.0 [https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SecurityUtils.html#method-c-secure_compare](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/classes/ActiveSupport/SecurityUtils.html#method-c-secure_compare)

Usage example:

```
def authenticate_by_token
  authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
    user = User.find_by(id: options[:uid])
    if user && ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(user.auth_token, token)
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That is not a correct usage of `secure_compare` in 4.2.0. Values need to be of the same length(see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e4a6dd147453aedecda7938a5650fcc2ff6febe9/activesupport/lib/active_support/security_utils.rb#L5-L20). The one to use on raw strings is `variable_size_secure_compare`.

Comment: Curious, that in the latest version they have swapped the names of the methods, so now the one to use on raw strings is `secure_compare`, and the other is `fixed_length_secure_compare`. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3b4f14dc43f09addb50c546ffe23b9e03eafed20/activesupport/lib/active_support/security_utils.rb

Comment: A more detailed explanation for `secure_compare` would have also helped based on the question !!!